# How to fix mismatched css grid cell sizes?

Tags: css-grid

The following responsive css grid code produces cells with mismatched sizes. I can't for the life of me figure out how this is possible.

```
#service-icons {
    display: grid;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 1fr));
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.service-icon {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[The page in question can be found here.](https://vedanamedia.com/permalinks/stackoverflow/20200917%20-%20Grid%20cell%20size%20mismatch/Connect%20Mat-Su%20%E2%80%93%20for%20a%20healthier%20community%20(9_17_2020%208_10_30%20PM).html) (Be sure to shrink the browser window to ensure use of mobile styling.)

Here is a screenshot showing the erroneous result:

[image: screen-shot.jpg]

Comment: The text on the bottom is defining the width of the cell and the images are just stretching to fill it. switch to `minmax(100px,1fr)` so all cells matches the longest cell which is the one with  the longest word

Comment: Zohir, pointing out that the text element was determining the width of the icon allowed me to fix it. If you want to answer this question I will accept it.

Comment: I don't think it's answer worthy, happy to help though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Zohir's comment under the question, the mismatched sizes can be accounted for by the different widths of the text elements. The larger text size pushes the grid cell size beyond its minimum. Allowing the text element to overflow within a new parent element fixed the problem in practice.